# Set height for responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position, height

I'm making a responsive website. But I can't set the height to a responsive height. Does anyone know how I can do this with CSS?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="slider_wrapper">
                <ul id="image_slider">
                    <li><img src="images/slider-1.jpg"></li>
                    <li><img src="images/slider-2.jpg"></li>
                    <li><img src="images/slider-3.jpg"></li>
                    <li><img src="images/slider-4.jpg"></li>
                </ul>                   
                <span class="nvgt" id="prev"></span>
                <span class="nvgt" id="next"></span>
            </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.slider_wrapper{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 85%;
}
#image_slider{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    /*Chrom default padding for ul is 40px */
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
#image_slider li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is very vague, what do you exactly want with the height?

Comment: As you can see is the width in %. This makes it responsive in width. But how can I make it responsive in width AND height?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `body` and `html` height to 100%, and then just ajust the `container` height to 100%.

I suggest using to `body` and `html` `min-height: 100%;`.

```
.body, .html {
   min-height: 100%;
}

.container{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 100%; 
}
```

And then just play with the heights.

Comment: IT doesn't work over here... :(

This is the CSS code of my body:
body, html{
    background: url('../images/background.png') no-repeat fixed center;
    min-height: 100%;
}